# Any alternative to "org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout" in Java default Libraries?

Tags: java, transactions, ejb, wildfly, jta

We have several projects using Schedulers and deployed in Wildfly.

```
import javax.ejb.AccessTimeout;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Schedules;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.ejb.TimerService;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.TransactionTimeout;

@Startup
@Singleton
@AccessTimeout(value = 10, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public class CustomerTeamsScheduler {

  @Schedules ({
    @Schedule(hour = "13", minute = "00", persistent = false),
    @Schedule(hour = "23", minute = "00", persistent = false)
  })
  @TransactionTimeout(value = 20, unit = TimeUnit.HOURS)
  public void schedule() {
```

For some projects, We are using TransactionTimeout which is ejb annotation.
Is there any annotation in Java library (not third party) which help in managing Transaction Timeout?

Comment: You can set a global value, but I'm not aware of a Jakarta EE annotation.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins: Global value means?

Comment: What I mean is that there is a setting for it in the EJB subsystem or in a `jboss-ejb.xml` file https://docs.wildfly.org/26.1/Developer_Guide.html#transaction-timeout.